# Additional Static IP without LoadBalancer in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We have followed the instructions from [Using Protocol Forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding/) to add additional static IPs to our VM; which does the job.

But few days later, we found an additional service charge added to our billing -  "Compute Engine Network Load Balancing: Forwarding Rule Minimum Service Charge in APAC". Is there a way to have multiple static IPs attached to an VM without Load Balancing?

After playing with the [Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/), we found it will add quite an amount of monthly fee using 1000G of bandwidth.  So can anyone kindly explain how to calculate the bandwidth cost using Forward Rule vs single static IP?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Google has recently added support for [multiple network interfaces](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/10/with-multiple-network-interfaces-connect-third-party-devices-to-GCP-workloads.html). Using this you can [create an instance](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#creating_virtual_machine_instances_with_multiple_network_interfaces) with two or more interfaces and have one external IP on each one of them. The IP can be static or ephemeral.